# Organising a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript (jQuery) 'init' file with various variables/event handlers and functions that are currently written in no particular order. I've read that it's good to organise these by declaring variables at the top of the file, using an init function and binding event handlers etc.

Here is the file in its full and here in [codepen](http://codepen.io/robbo/pen/KdKxpY).

It would be useful to just have a few pointers on how to organise this file a little better.

```
var w = $(window).width(),
    h = $(window).height(),
    screenMedium = 780,
    screenLarge = 920;

//remove error on fields on keydown
$('.form .error').on('keydown', 'input, textarea', function(){
    $(this)
        .parent()
        .removeClass('error')
        .end()
        .next()
        .remove('small');
});

// sticky navigation
function stickyNavigation() {

    var browserWidth = $(window).width();

    if(browserWidth >= 920) {

        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 175){  
            $('body').addClass("sticky");
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass("sticky");
        }

    }

}


//homepage video
var $video = $('#thevideo');
var video = $('#thevideo')[0];
var loaded = false;

$('#play-video-2').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#thevideo-wrap').addClass('show-video');
    $('.playbutton').addClass('playing');
    setTimeout(function(){
        video.play();
    }, 1000);
});

$('.playbutton').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $button = $(this);
    var $holder = $(this).parent();
    var state = $button.hasClass('paused') ? 'paused'   :
                $button.hasClass('playing') ? 'playing' : '';

    if( state === 'playing' ){
        video.pause();
        $button.addClass('paused');

        return;
    }

    if( state === 'paused' ){
        video.play();
        $button.removeClass('paused');

        return;
    }

});

$video.on('ended', function(){
    $('#thevideo-wrap').removeClass('show-video');
    $('.playbutton').removeClass('playing');
});


//off canvas nav toggle
$('.off-canvas-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var direction = $('.off-canvas__container').data('off-canvas-direction');

    if ( $('#mobile-search').hasClass('show-mobile-search') ) {
        $('#mobile-search').removeClass('show-mobile-search');
    }

    $('.off-canvas').toggleClass('off-canvas--' + direction);
    $('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('pushed');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

//off canvas mobile nav
$('.off-canvas__content').on('click', '.nav-click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $this = $(this);
    $item = $this.parent('.nav__item');
    $item.toggleClass('nav__item--open');
    $this.children('i').toggleClass('icon-minus').toggleClass('icon-plus');

    if($item.hasClass('nav__item--open')) {
      $item.siblings().removeClass('nav__item--open');
      $item.siblings().children('.nav-click').children().removeClass('icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus');
    }

});


//toggle search
function toggleSearch() {

    if ($('body').hasClass('sticky')) {

        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600, function() {

            $('#mobile-search').addClass('show-mobile-search');
            $('#main-header').addClass('mobile-search-open');
            $('.show-mobile-search').find('#mobile-query').focus();

        });

    } else {

        $('#mobile-search').toggleClass('show-mobile-search');
        $('#main-header').toggleClass('mobile-search-open');
        $('.show-mobile-search').find('#mobile-query').focus();

    }


}

$('.search-link-mobile').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    toggleSearch();

});


//footer nav toggle
if (w < screenMedium) {

    $('.footer-list-title').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).children('span').toggleClass('icon-minus').toggleClass('icon-plus').end().next().slideToggle(200);

    });

}


//desktop navigation dropdown
$('.has-subnav').on({

    mouseenter: function () {

        if (!$('body').hasClass('sticky')) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.children('a').addClass('active');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $this.find('.main-nav-dropdown').addClass('main-nav-opened');
                $('.off-canvas').addClass('open');
            }, 300);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $this.find('.main-nav-dropdown-list').addClass('main-nav-list-opened');
            }, 400);
        }

    },

    mouseleave: function () {

        if (!$('body').hasClass('sticky')) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.children('a').removeClass('active');
            $this.find('.main-nav-dropdown-list').removeClass('main-nav-list-opened');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $this.find('.main-nav-dropdown').removeClass('main-nav-opened');
                $('.off-canvas').removeClass('open');
            }, 300);

        }

    }

});

//homepage desktop hero slider
var heroSlider = $('#hero-slider').bxSlider({
    pagerCustom: '#hero-pager',
    auto: true,
    mode: 'fade',
    speed: 800,
    pause: 8000,
    video: true,
    autoHover: true,
    onSliderLoad: function() {
        $('body').addClass('loaded');

        var browserWidth = $(window).width();

        if(browserWidth >= 920) {
            var current = 0;
            var themeID = $('#slide-index-'+current).find('.hero-inner').data('theme');
            if (themeID === 1) {
                $('body').addClass('slider-theme-light');
            } else {
                $('body').addClass('slider-theme-dark');
            }
        }
    },
    onSlideBefore: function() {

        var browserWidth = $(window).width();

        if(browserWidth >= 920) {
            var current = heroSlider.getCurrentSlide();
            var themeID = $('#slide-index-'+current).find('.hero-inner').data('theme');
            if (themeID === 1) {
                $('body').addClass('slider-theme-light').removeClass('slider-theme-dark');
            } else {
                $('body').addClass('slider-theme-dark').removeClass('slider-theme-light');
            }
        }
    },
});


//scroll to main content
$("#to-content").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#main").offset().top
    }, 1000);
});


//featured shows slider
$('#featured-slider')
    .on('init', function(event, slick){
        $(this).addClass('loaded');
    })
    .slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        mobileFirst: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 4000,
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        prevArrow: '<a href="#" data-role="none" class="slick-arrow slick-prev" aria-label="previous">Previous</a>',
        nextArrow: '<a href="#" data-role="none" class="slick-arrow slick-next" aria-label="next">Next</a>',
        customPaging : function(slider, i) {
            return '<span class="slick-dot"><span></span></span>';
        },
        responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1600,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 5,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: true
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 1300,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: true
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 780,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                arrows: true
            }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2
          }
        }
      ]
});



//journey wall
$('#journal-wall').mixitup({
    onMixStart: function() {
        $("#journal-wall .journal-item img").trigger("unveil");
    }
});

//lazy load journey all item images
$("#journal-wall .journal-item img").unveil(20, function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
        this.style.opacity = 1;
    });
});

//toggle journal nav
$('.journal-list-title').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).children('span').toggleClass('icon-minus').toggleClass('icon-plus').end().next().slideToggle(200);

});


//article fitvids
$('.article').fitVids();


$(window).scroll(function() {

    stickyNavigation();

});

$(window).load(function() {

    var w = $(window).width();

    if (w >= 600) {

        $('#journal-wall .journal-item').conformity();

    }

});


$(window).on("debouncedresize", function( event ) {

    var w = $(window).width();

    if (w < 920) {
        $('body').removeClass('sticky').removeClass('slider-theme-light').removeClass('slider-theme-dark');
        if ($('.bx-wrapper').length && $('body').hasClass('home')) {
            heroSlider.destroySlider();
        }
    } else {
        if (!$('.bx-wrapper').length && $('body').hasClass('home')) {
            heroSlider.reloadSlider();
        }
    }

    if (w >= 600) {

        $('#journal-wall .journal-item').conformity();

    } else {

        $('#journal-wall .journal-item').removeAttr('style');
    }   

});
```

Comment: It may be useful to split pieces of your code into reusable modules and then include them in separately where pages require them.

Comment: This sounds interesting, I've always checked to see if an element exists with `.length` in the past which seems clunky. Do you have any examples/tutorials I could use?

Comment: If you added a certain module (or component) to a page which required it, that would imply the element already exists on the page, solving that issue.

Comment: For instance, Vue.js implements a components structure that has a template associated. The template creates the elements that component requires automatically.

Comment: Does this mean I'd have to split my 'init.js' file up into separate files?

Comment: Sorry still a newb at javascript (jQuery) hence why I just write all my handlers/functions in a linear fashion as and when I come to them in a build.

Comment: Yes I would create a nicer file structure to aid larger code bases, maybe a modules folder with each file being a separate module?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27657/discussion-between-rob-morris-and-jamesking56).